# ANOVA, Kruskal-Wallis test

Tags: regression

I’m making a Maters’ Thesis Survey. I conducted a survey with 110 respondents. The first table on the picture is with calculated results. Now, I need to calculate Table 2 with ANOVA or Kruskal-Wallis test where is applicable but I don’t know how to do it. I have no experience in statistics or ANOVA.

Table 1 is for the questions for consumer buying INTENTIONS for eco-products and Table 2 is for the Product PRICE (marketing instruments) and I need to find out if the Product Price influence consumer buying intentions for eco-products (The question was –Would you pay higher price for eco-products?).

Thank you. [image: img]

Comment: What is your preferred statistics software or programming language?

Comment: @user269938 You will need to ask a specific question -- you don't ask any questions at all that I can discern. We won't be able to teach you very broad /general things ("teach me ANOVA and Kruskal-Wallis tests" would be too broad) nor can we teach you how to use software from scratch. Have you considered looking at various resources on-line (videos, notes) and reading some books on the topic?

Comment: I think you need to take at least two statistics courses. ANOVA is usually covered in the second course in "field" subjects (like psychology, sociology etc.). 

Or else, you need to hire a consultant.

You might be able to learn it from a book (as @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica ) suggests, but it would take a while to learn to do it well. You need practice.

Comment: @user269938 If you're able to edit this so as to ask a specific question we may be able to help